# Scraping dynamic data from IE using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, dynamic, handle

I am trying to use VBA to automate orders in Internet Explore. At this point, I have trouble using the commands like "getElementsByClassName", "getElementByID" and so on. I searched about those commands, read and tested some  examples, but I still can't figure out how they work. I will state my goal and my doubts.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="z-row-content" id="s0GQm-cell">
<input class="form-control z-textbox" id="s0GQm" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

My goal: I just need the id "s0GQm" to point my orders. However, this id is partially dynamic and changes everytime I reset the window. The first 4 characters will change and only the "m" will stand. These dynamic characters repeat for all over the HTML code, so if I get it from anywhere I just needed to update all the id's and everything would run fine.

Therefore, I would like to understand how these functions can be used to identify this exact dynamic code. More specifically, what do these codes do exacly? What is the ".item(0)" or length of "getElementsByClassName"?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements based on matching by class name. class is an attribute of an element. You place the class name, or compound classes within the () after getElementsByClassName. As it is a collection you index into it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff975198(v=vs.94). Length is how many elements are present in the collection.

Comment: Can you include the code you tried, along with what didn't work, and I will write an answer. At present your question is off topic, imo, as there is no code to debug and more of a request for a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for posting. I did not mean to ask you to do the job, but it is as simple as extract that dynamic code, nothing else. I just wanted to understand how these commands work. I understand it is a "collection of elements", but I don't know what is exacly one element. Is it one single character, or a part like "id=..." or "type=..", or maybe whatever is writen after "<inpute". I just wanted to know exacly what are these elements. I'll take a look into this link.

Comment: elements refers to html.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element See [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Syntax) . And yes,  there is likely a way to do a partial match on the element id attribute that could work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, QHarr. This single image was very clarifying and I'll read this page to understand further.

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.

Comment: You want to take a look at attribute = value css selectors applied via querySelector or querySelectorAll to potentially solve your problem. You can use a the contains or ends with operators * or $ to solve your id attribute problem